# How to add a commented out or a "note" in Rmarkdown beamer?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I am trying to add the equivalent of a lyx "note" or just a comment (something I can see but won't run) in an Rmarkdown beamer presentation.

"#" obviously creates new slides, so that won't work as it doesn in R

Comment: This was marked as duplicate yet the answer is different because it is Beamer. I do not think it is a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

On a new line, type:

```
[//]: (This is my fuarking comment!)
```

Comment: This is the syntax for footnotes. Comments in markdown follow the html syntax: `<!-- my comment -->`